# Passing Argument to Lumen Job

Tags: php, laravel, twilio, lumen, twilio-php

I am building an app in Lumen that sends text messages with Twilio.  I am in the process of creating the Job that actually handles the sending of the message.  I dispatch the Job directly from the routes file.  Eventually, the "To" phone number will be entered in a form so I'm having it passed into the job as an argument.

Here is my Job class:

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

class FiveMessageJob extends Job
{

    protected $number;
    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($number)
    {
        $this->number = $number;
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {

        //dd($this->number);

        // this line loads the library
        require base_path('twilio-php-master/Services/Twilio.php');

        $account_sid = 'xxxxxxxxxxxx';
        $auth_token = 'xxxxxxxxxxxx';
        $client = new \Services_Twilio($account_sid, $auth_token);

        $client->account->messages->create(array(
            'To' => $this->number,
            'From' => "xxxxxxxxxxx",
            'Body' => "What's up Stackoverflow?"
        ));
    }
}
```

Here is the route that dispatches the job:

```
$app->get('/', function () use ($app) {
    $number = "+15555555555";

    dispatch(new \App\Jobs\FiveMessageJob($number));

    return view('index');
});
```

I am getting the Twilio error: `A 'To' phone number is required.`

When I `dd($this->number)` inside of the handle function, it returns *null*.

Obviously the $number argument isn't being passed through.  I'm sure I'm missing something obvious so I could use a second set of eyes and any help y'all can offer.

Thanks.

Comment: What happens if you call `dd($this->number)` in the constructor of the job?

Comment: It returns the correct number

Comment: Wow, so the job is not saving its state? Can you inspect what it's entering in the database?

Comment: So the number randomly started working...But now the exact same thing is happening with a newly added $message argument.  Dumps correctly from the constructor but is _null_ inside of the handle function.  Twilio says that a Message Body is required.